# One-liner to collect multiple pattern matches and delete them at the same time

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a bunch of strings that look like the following:

```
str = 'CA3 03223-DG 0101-CA2 0101-CA1 0101 pyramidal cells c (PC-c)'
```

That is, there are a bunch of hyphen-separated leading strings like "CA3 03223" followed by some words (in the example above, "pyramidal cells c (PC-c)".  I would like, in one line, to gather all of the leading, hyphen-separated pieces into an array while deleting them from `str`.  At the end of this line, I should have an array that looks like this:

```
['CA3 03223', 'DG 0101', 'CA2 0101', 'CA1 0101']
```

And `str` should be:

```
'pyramidal cells c (PC-c)'
```

My current solution is:

```
myarray = []; match = ''
myarray << match.strip[0..-2] while (match = str.slice!(/[A-Z0-9]{2,3} \d{3,}[\-\s]/))
```

Rather ugly, I know.  How can I shorten this to a single reasonable-length line?  I'm looking for something like `String#scan` that deletes the matches it finds.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a replace function? You can replace the match with empty string.

Comment: Your solution doesn't appear to actually work. `myarray` remains empty and `str` is unchanged (Ruby 1.9.3).

Comment: I can confirm that the current "solution" fails on both 1.9.3 and 1.8.7. Further, I must ask: What's your motivation for doing this in one line? That doesn't seem conducive to clarity or maintainability...

Comment: How do you plan to delimit the trailing words from the rest of your string? If you use dashes as a delimiter you will get `CA1 0101 pyramidal cells c (PC-c)` in your array.

Comment: I apologize for posting something that didn't work.  I've edited it to make it work.  While a long and convoluted line of code is not conducive to clarity, it is possible that a clear one-liner exists, which is why I'm asking this question.  The idea I'm after is simple enough-- basically I'm looking for what String#scan! would be if it existed.

Comment: @CodeGnome The dash is not a good delimiter here, I know-- but this is the data that I've got, I don't have a choice.  Trailing words can be separated out from the leading substrings by matching the leading substrings to the regex in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is probably the cleanest:

```
myarray, str = str.scan(re), str.gsub(re, '')
```

you can move the regexp inline if you want a one-liner but I wouldn't

Comment: Nice.  Cleaner than my solution, but I'm hoping for something where the regex does not have to be entered twice so it can be inline.